# toString(); java

Tags: java, tostring

Can anyone see why my `toString()` method isn't working? It compiles just fine but when I run it there is a runtime error:

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ExamMarks {

    // fields
    private String moduleName;
    private int moduleCode;
    private int year;
    private int[] numbers;

    // methods
    public static int highestMark(int[] numbers) {
        int highest = numbers[numbers.length - 1];
        int i = numbers[0];
        for (i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] > numbers[i + 1]) {
                highest = numbers[i];
            }
        }
        return highest;
    }

    public static double averageMark(int[] numbers) {
        int sum = 0;
        double average = 0.000;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            sum = numbers[i] + sum;
            average = sum / numbers.length;
        }
        return average;
    }

    // Constructor
    public ExamMarks() {
        moduleName = "Object Oriented Programming";
        moduleCode = 5015;
        year = 2013;
    }

    // toString
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String result = ("The title of this module is : " + moduleName
                + "The code number of this module is: " + moduleCode
                + "The year of the Exam is: " + year + "Array average = "
                + averageMark(numbers) + "Highest grade = " + highestMark(numbers));
        return result;
    }

    // Tester
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExamMarks grade = new ExamMarks();
        Scanner percentages = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] numbers = new int[20];
        double x = averageMark(numbers);

        System.out.println("Please enter 20 marks");

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = percentages.nextInt();

        }

        System.out.println(grade);
    }
}
```

And this is error I get

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at ExamMarks.averageMark(ExamMarks.java:26) 
    at ExamMarks.toString(ExamMarks.java:42) 
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source) 
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(Unknown Source) 
    at ExamMarks.main(ExamMarks.java:65) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) 
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:27‌​2)
```

Comment: @user2039888 Don't post relevant informations in comments. Use [[edit]] option instead to add it to your question.

Comment: line 26: for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){                        :Working perfectly fine before started editing the toString();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NullPointerException is here.
private int [] numbers;

numbers is null in your instance.

When you call grade.toString(), the method calls

```
 public static double averageMark(int [] numbers){
    int sum = 0;  
    double average = 0.000;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){   // !!!! numbers is null
```

Answer (score 0):

The fields "moduleName", "moduleCode" and "year" are not being setted. Try to set them before call System.out.println(grade);

Comment: Create 'setters' for these fields? then use them in the to String?

Comment: Don't you have getters and setters methods for these fields?

Comment: No! like I said am beginner. I presume I need them in this instance?

Comment: Check this article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming). It's one of the four OOP fundamentals :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your `toString()` function resilient to Exceptions.

At the most basic level, you can add a `try` and `catch` around the whole implementation OR make the functions `averageMark(numbers)` and `highestMark(numbers)` deal with the null pointer exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You never set the `private int [] numbers;` field of the `ExamMarks` class.

`numbers` in the `toString()` method belong to the instance of the `ExamMarks` class, while `numbers` in the `main(...)` is just a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

you called

```
averageMark(numbers);
```

directly. So the numbers you are using as parameters are fine.

But the toString() method also calls this method, but with an not initialized class field 'numbers'.

you have to make 'numbers' static too and set some values to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your members are != null before concatenating with the + operator.

If you use eclipse use rightclick -> source -> generate toString() ... it generates a simple `toString` method in your class where you only need to change the text.

Works generally great and it is easy to use.